# Spring Boot Thymeleaf - Split Data into 2 columns

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm using spring boot 2.5 along with Thymeleaf 3.0.12. I have a list of strings which i want to display in two columns. Below is code snippet i'm using as of now:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check"  th:each="service : ${services}" th:if="${serviceStat.odd}">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="serviceChk" th:id="${'serviceChkBox_'+serviceStat.count}"/> 
            <label  class="form-check-label" th:text="${'myStr'+'_'+serviceStat.count}"></label>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-check" th:each="service : ${services}" th:if="${serviceStat.even}">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="serviceChk" th:id="${'serviceChkBox_'+serviceStat.count}"/> 
            <label  class="form-check-label" th:text="${'myStr'+'_'+serviceStat.count}"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works as expected.
[image]

But this approach needs two times of list iterations. I doubt if my list is huge, my page may become slow. Is there a way to achieve the same in single iteration?

Comment: Why not use CSS to create the columns?

Comment: Where is serviceStat from?

Comment: @aksappy it is aggregation of variable, 'service', and suffix 'Stat' which will be automatically available in Thymeleaf

Comment: Is the even / odd stat in services with a ratio of 1:1? If it is, `col-sm-6` will automatically keep them in two columns and only one loop is needed.

Comment: @aksappy i didnt get you ? How ?

Comment: col-sm-6 follows an auto layout grid system in bootstrap. There are 12 cells (predefined) in a grid and col-sm-6 takes 6 cells in a small screen. After the 12 cell, 2nd col-sm-6, the content is wrapped into next row automatically.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe im poor in CSS, so tried to implement this way.. can you suggest how can we do it in CSS using bootstrap?

Comment: @aksappy i think you are saying to use "col-sm-12" and content is aligned accordingly... but its not giving out put as shown above.. its auto adjusting strings like in one row, its showing 3 strings with checkboxes and in another row 2 strings (if string is large) etc.. but i want columns are aligned properly like shown in screenshot...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234789/discussion-between-aksappy-and-kaluva).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this in a single loop. The trick is to perform the `th:each` with the `col-sm-6` div and bootstrap will take care of aligning them in two columns. The OP happens to have the `th:each` inside the `col-sm-6` div.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" th:each="service : ${services}">
        <div class="form-check">
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="serviceChk" th:id="${'serviceChkBox_'+serviceStat.count}"/>
            <label  class="form-check-label" th:text="${'myStr'+'_'+serviceStat.count}"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

NOTE - `col-sm-6` is a breakpoint for small screens. Use https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#grid-options to pick the right breakpoints for your requirement.